# Scripting a major multi-file multi-server FTP upload: is smart interrupted transfer resuming possible?

Tags: bash, upload, ftp

I'm trying to upload several hundred files to 10+ different servers. I previously accomplished this using FileZilla, but I'm trying to make it go using just common command-line tools and shell scripts so that it isn't dependent on working from a particular host.

Right now I have a shell script that takes a list of servers (in ftp://user:pass@host.com format) and spawns a new background instance of 'ftp ftp://user:pass@host.com < batch.file' for each server.

This works in principle, but as soon as the connection to a given server times out/resets/gets interrupted, it breaks. While all the other transfers keep going, I have no way of resuming whichever transfer(s) have been interrupted. The only way to know if this has happened is to check each receiving server by hand. This sucks!

Right now I'm looking at wput and lftp, but these would require installation on whichever host I want to run the upload from. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in a simpler way?

Comment: There is no simpler way to do it. Builtin `ftp` or `sftp` commands are not very smart and provide functions of copy, move , delete, list files and that's about it. You either, have to come up with a solution of yours but that may be re-inventing the wheel since such tools are already available, so you'd better off installing and using them instead.

Comment: Go for lftp reverse mirroring  unless you want to reinvent wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). It's really good at only transferring just the data that's been changed during a transfer. Much more efficient than FTP! More info on how to resume interrupted connections with an example can be found [here](http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/11/19/resume-scprsync-file-transfer/). Hope that helps!